# Call React native fetch api using state value on RNPickerSelect onvaluechange

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, fetch-api

I am calling fetch api (getDieselRequisitionList()) using state value in constructor like below.

```
this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
            this.setState({
                diesel_data: []
            })
            this.getDieselRequisitionList(this.state.selectedStatus, this.state.selectedYear, this.state.Month[this.state.selectedMonthIndex].id)
        });
```

i have 3 dropdown. i want to call getDieselRequisitionList automatically on RNPickerSelect onvaluechange without calling function in onvaluechange

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is work for me

```
onValueChange={(value, index) => {
  // console.warn(index, value)
  this.setState({
    selectedYear: value,
    selectedYearIndex: index == 0 ? null : index - 1,
  });
  if (value != selectedYear) {
    this.getDieselRequisitionListOnChange(this.state.selectedStatus, value, this.state.selectedMonth)
  }
}}
```